# jQuery: how to change output with click and change functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I have a group of fields that can be added and removed. One of these fields contains a set of numbers that are added to produce a sum. You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/beehive/HGJck/

Here's my problem: the sum does not change when I select a different number value when the form first loads, and there is only one group of fields (nothing added). It only changes after I've added or removed fields. How can I fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* Add & Remove */
var removeButton = "<button id='remove'>Remove</button>";
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('div.container:last').after($('div.container:first').clone());
    $('div.container:last').append(removeButton);

    /* Sum */
    $(".number").change(function() {
        var combined = -10;
        $(".number").each(function() {
            combined += parseInt(this.value);
        });
        $("#sum").html(combined);
    }).trigger("change"); 

    return false;

});

$('#remove').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.container').remove();
});

});​
```

Comment: don't forget the radix parameter to `parseInt` !

Comment: Why are you declaring combined at -10?  Why not 0?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the sum calculation into its own function and set combined to 0 instead of -10: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HGJck/2/)**

```
/* Add & Remove */
var removeButton = "<button id='remove'>Remove</button>";
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('div.container:last').after($('div.container:first').clone());
    $('div.container:last').append(removeButton);
    sum();
    return false;
});

$('#remove').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.container').remove();
    sum();
});

function sum() {
    /* Sum */
    $(".number").change(function() {
        var combined = 0;
        $(".number").each(function() {
            combined += parseInt(this.value);
        });
        $("#sum").html(combined);
    }).trigger("change");
}​
```

Comment: Small correction to your code, place the function `sum()` on load. So intially sum value will be `10`. Updated **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/HGJck/3/)**

Comment: @SivaCharan - true or just set the HTML to 10.